# passing address of an array in a function for initialization

Tags: c, arrays

Hi im trying to use a function to initialize an array with random number. somehow i get this error that i couldnt be able to solve

```
void arrayInit(int *A, int n){
  int i;
  for ( i = 0; i < n; ++i)
  {
    A[i] = rand();
  } 
}
```

call arrayInit() in main

```
int main(void){

  int array1[1000];

  arrayInit(&array1, 1000);

    return 0;
}
```

I get error saying:

```
csort.c:62:13: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘arrayInit’ from incompatible pointer type
   arrayInit(&array1, 1000);
             ^
csort.c:8:6: note: expected ‘int *’ but argument is of type ‘int (*)[1000]’
 void arrayInit(int *A, int n){
      ^
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the call for `arrayInit` to be like this:

```
arrayInit(array1, 1000);
```

Instead of this:

```
arrayInit(&array1, 1000);
```

The name of an array decays to be a pointer to the first element, which is what your function needs.

Comment: You've fixed the bug, but `array1` isn't a pointer to the first element, but instead decays to it. For example, `sizeof(array1)` isn't `sizeof(int*)`.

Answer (score 1):

When you have

```
int array1[1000];
```

The type of `&array1` is `int (*)[1000]`, which is not what `arrayInit` expects. By using

```
arrayInit(arra1, 1000);
```

you are letting compiler decay the array to a pointer, which of of type `int*` in your case.

An array does not decay to a pointer in couple of cases:

1. When you use the `&` operator.
2. When you use the `sizeof` operator.

Answer (score 0):

The identifier of any array is a *type* *  itself. 
So you need to call your function like this:
`arrayInit(array1, 1000);`.

Calling your function with an address of a pointer(`&array1)` would require a `int** A`(a pointer to a pointer type) in your function definition, which is certainly not the thing to do in this case, since the indexing in this case would also give an error.

Answer (score 0):

you can call arrayInit() using the '&' as:

arrayInit(&array1[0], 1000);